# Send files to WiFi printer

Tags: android, file, client-server, thermal-printer

I am developing an application in which from my mobile I am sending files to the WiFi printer by IP address and port number, which are .txt, .png, .jpg, .doc. They should be printed from the printer. I have tried following code but it is giving me output for .txt file only. What changes are required to get output of all type of files??? Please help...

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private Socket client;
     private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
     private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
     private OutputStream outputStream;
     private Button button;
     private TextView text;
     private EditText etIp, etPort;
     int port=0;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   //reference to the send button
      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);   //reference to the text view
      etIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      etPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      //Button press event listener
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {


         //create file instance
           port=Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString());
           File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/bluetooth/AnyFile.txt"); 
        try 
        {

         client = new Socket(etIp.getText().toString(), port);

         byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; //create a byte array to file

         fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
         bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);  

         bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //read the file

         outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

         outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //write file to the output stream byte by byte
         outputStream.flush();
         bufferedInputStream.close();
         outputStream.close();
         client.close();

         text.setText("File Sent");


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }


       }
      });

     }
    }



Manifest file

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: how you solve this ??? please share it.

Comment: @Hardik..Are you talking about code explanation or what? Mention it...

Comment: Means sample you provide is working ??? i also want to develop this..

Comment: Yup...but only for .txt files..
not any images...
If you find any solution for it, help me to solve it...

Comment: have you implemented it...??

Comment: above code is not working for me. Can you help me ?

Comment: what u have done so far???

Comment: I used your code with my ip and port with no error in logcat though printer not working. Any suggestion ?

Comment: have u connected ur printer and device to the same router??? (in same network)

Comment: I am using this above code with   client = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 631);    but not working tell me how you trick for this.

Comment: @kiranboghra: pass ur port number also

Comment: @anil bhatiya yes I am also pass port 631 for printer but not working . is printer direc;y print thia raw data?

Comment: printer should have appropriate circuit (on which c code is loaded to handle binary data... nd about this i dnt knw...)

Comment: @AnilBhatiya, have you found any solution for other format yet??

Comment: @CrazyLearner yes... actually I've successfully done for .BMP image format and for .txt files..

Comment: @AnilBhatiya I am facing some alignment problems in printing txt files. Do you have any time to chat with me for discussing this matter with you? If yes, tell me your convenient time for chatting...

Comment: @CrazyLearner... you can chat with me on google hangouts as I don't frequently come here... my id is anil25bhatiya@gmail.com

Comment: @AnilBhatiya thanks a lot for sharing your gmail id, I have invited you already through my account (bipu.nstu@gmail.com)....

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit old question. Android 4.4 provides you this functionality.

[Please check these instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jpg, png, and doc would need to be parsed into a file format the printer recognizes such as pdf or PS. Then the file could be streamed to the printer.

Comment: You could accept an answer or post your solution to benefit the community.