# Wifi printer not printing the pages android

Tags: android, sockets, printing, wifi

I have using the following code:

```
Socket client = new Socket(etIp.getText().toString(), 515);

String printText = "This is a print test from Wifi";
byte[] mybytearray = printText.getBytes(); 


OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //write file to the output stream byte by byte
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
client.close();
```

Socket connection opened, and no exception while complete process of write data in output stream. But printer not eject the page.

Please help me what I have did wrong.

Comment: Why do you think this would work?  You're writing raw text to a printer.  I don't think any of them work that way.  They typically speak a language like PCL.

Comment: @GabeSechan This code referenced from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452437/send-files-to-wifi-printer) and this works for .txt files. And he also write the raw text.

Comment: I wrote printer firmware for 4 years (albeit a decade ago), and not a single printer I worked on would have printed out raw text sent to it.  It may work on some models, but I would not expect it to be universal.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have using Canon PIXMA MX430 printer. 
Is there any printer specific code I have to write on output stream?

Comment: @KetanAhir did you got any solutions share with me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send few more data for it to eject and let the printer know.

For Epson L355 I am appending a byte array at the end of my string.

```
byte[] EjectByteArray = {0X00, 0X0D, 0X0C, 0X1B, 0X40, 0X1B, 0X28, 0X52, 0X08, 0X00, 0X00, 0X52, 0X45, 0X4D, 0X4F, 0X54, 0X45, 0X31, 0X4C, 0X44, 0X00, 0X00, 0X1B, 0X00, 0X00, 0X00, 0X1B, 0X40, 0X1B, 0X28, 0X52, 0X08, 0X00, 0X00, 0X52, 0X45, 0X4D, 0X4F, 0X54, 0X45, 0X31, 0X4C, 0X44, 0X00, 0X00, 0X4A, 0X45, 0X01, 0X00, 0X00, 0X1B, 0X00, 0X00, 0X00};
```

You may need to run a Port sniffer and try to capture the last byte array being passed after a print is finished. It would give you a clue on how you should send an eject command. This is one works on me using port 9100 on Epson L355

```
outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); 
outputStream.write(EjectByteArray, 0, EjectByteArray.length); 
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
client.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` end of the line.this is work for me

```
String printText = "Finally its working \n";
```